# I get a type '{}' where I should be getting a type number (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript

In the following TypeScript code, which is a subset of a more complete class, I have some functions such as map and foldr. When I run code such as:

```
var s = new ArrayList<number>();
s.append(5, 6, 7, 8);

var i : number = s.foldr(max, 0);
```

I end up with an error such as "Type '{}" is not assignable to type 'number'." The way, I am figuring it, the type should be a number. I would justify it like this:

The type signature of foldr is: foldr(f : (x : T, y : B) => B, init : B) : B. Because T is from the ArrayList, it is a number. The function is passed init as 0, which is a number, and max is max(x : T, y : T) : T which sets B = T because x is T (even though they could be different Ts, they are not in this case).

But regardless, I still get this error. Is there a fundamental error I am making?

The code sample is below, also available on [gists](https://gist.github.com/iaefai/96759903ad0f309ab3ed) and on the [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=%0A%0Aclass%20ArrayList%3CT%3E%20%7B%0A%09private%20_data%20%3A%20Array%3CT%3E%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%09this._data%20%3D%20new%20Array%3CT%3E()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%09%0A%09public%20get%20length()%3Anumber%20%7B%20return%20%20this._data.length%3B%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20append(...items%20%3A%20T%5B%5D)%20%3A%20void%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._data%20%3D%20this._data.concat(items)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%09public%20get(n%20%3A%20number)%20%3A%20T%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._data%5Bn%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20foldr%3CB%3E(f%20%3A%20(x%20%3A%20T%2C%20y%20%3A%20B)%20%3D%3E%20B%2C%20init%20%3A%20B)%20%3A%20B%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(this.length%20%3D%3D%200)%20return%20init%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20result%20%3D%20init%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(var%20i%20%3D%20this._data.length%20-%201%3B%20i%20%3E%3D%200%3B%20--i)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20result%20%3D%20f(this._data%5Bi%5D%2C%20result)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20result%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20max%3CT%3E(x%20%3A%20T%2C%20y%20%3A%20T)%20%3A%20T%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20x%20%3E%20y%20%3F%20x%20%3A%20y%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20s%20%3D%20new%20ArrayList%3Cnumber%3E()%3B%0As.append(5%2C%206%2C%207%2C%208)%3B%0A%0Avar%20i%20%3A%20number%20%3D%20s.foldr(max%2C%200)%3B%0A).

```
class ArrayList<T> {
    private _data : Array<T>;

    public constructor() {
        this._data = new Array<T>();
    }

    public get length():number { return  this._data.length; }

    public append(...items : T[]) : void {
        this._data = this._data.concat(items);
    }

    public get(n : number) : T {
        return this._data[n];
    }

    public foldr<B>(f : (x : T, y : B) => B, init : B) : B {
        if (this.length == 0) return init;

        var result = init;

        for (var i = this._data.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            result = f(this._data[i], result);
        }

        return result;
    }

}

function max<T>(x : T, y : T) : T {
    return x > y ? x : y;
}

var s = new ArrayList<number>();
s.append(5, 6, 7, 8);

//  Type '{}" is not assignable to type 'number'.
var i : number = s.foldr(max, 0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `foldr` method in your example code takes a type argument, `<B>`.

```
var i : number = s.foldr<number>(max, 0);
```

Although, perhaps you intended it not to. This version, which re-uses the `T` type argument means it all just works (although you will have to ensure this is what you intended).

```
public foldr(f : (x : T, y : T) => T, init : T) : T {
    if (this.length == 0) return init;

    var result = init;

    for (var i = this._data.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        result = f(this._data[i], result);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I wasn't intending this, because it should be able to be more generic. The reason it is like this is primarily because of Haskell [source for foldr](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#foldr), the type being (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b.

I believe the reason is that you might want to convert the type of the list into something else, for example to a string.

Comment: If you want it to be more generic, use the first code block (i.e. supply a type argument). If you want it to be `number` because the ArrayList has the number type argument, use the second.

Comment: So in essence, the type argument must be provided, it does not infer from the parameters?

Comment: Reading section 1.9 of the specification, it does indicate that it can infer arguments — but it always is using lambdas in the examples. So maybe what I really want figure out is the limits of this inference are.

Comment: Don't rule out better inference in the future - but this is the current position.